# Did Baum invent his method for killing witches?

Tags: the-wizard-of-oz

The Wicked Witch of the West is killed when water is poured on her head.

I don't remember any other fairy tales where this happens. **Did Baum *invent* this method for killing witches?**

Richard provided/found the clip/quote:

> ". . . the Witch began to shrink and fall away. "See what you have done!" she screamed. "In a minute I shall melt away."
>
> "I am very sorry, indeed," said Dorothy, who was truly frightened to see the Witch actually melting away like brown sugar before her eyes.
>
> "Didn't you know water would be the end of me?" asked the Witch, in a wailing, despairing voice.
>
> "Of course not," answered Dorothy; "how should I?""

[I'm melting, I'm melting! Oh what a world!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aopdD9Cu-So&feature=youtu.be&t=25s)

**Apparently Dorothy didn't know about it, but did the world know about it?**

Comment: [I'm melting, I'm melting! Oh what a world!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aopdD9Cu-So&feature=youtu.be&t=25s)

Comment: "*. . . the Witch began to shrink and fall away. "See what you have done!" she screamed. "In a minute I shall melt away."

"I am very sorry, indeed," said Dorothy, who was truly frightened to see the Witch actually melting away like brown sugar before her eyes.

"Didn't you know water would be the end of me?" asked the Witch, in a wailing, despairing voice.

"Of course not," answered Dorothy; "how should I?"*"

Comment: @Richard should incorporate the video/quote? Or why are you commenting them?

Comment: You're welcome to incorporate them if you want. They don't answer the question, they just add info.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Baum has another passage earlier in the book where he explains that the Witch feared water because she was all dried up. That might be relevant background information.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't seem to state this explicitly. I think the quote I was thinking of was "The Witch did not bleed where she was bitten, for she was so wicked that the blood in her had dried up many years before."

Comment: Did this title need to be worded in a non-spoilery way?

Comment: @ThePopMachine The book is well over 100 years old, the most popular film adaptation is almost 80 years old. I think people who know who Baum is and don't know the gist of the story *deserve* to be spoilered xD

Comment: @Armin:  So... you're agreeing with me?   This question should just ask is *Did Baum invent the idea that water makes witches melt?* .

Comment: @ThePopMachine that wouldn't be less spoilery. Someone who didn't know how the story ends and knows who Baum was would immediately know that some witch would melt...

Comment: @Armin:   The crux of my question is that 100-year old material, that essentially everyone has seen, doesn't need to be protected by spoiler-resistant language.   And it's not too much of a spoiler anyways.   That witches can be killed by water doesn't necessarily mean that one is.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### The idea that water is proof against supernatural evil is has quite a long pedigree:

- In folklore, vampires sometimes are thought to be unable to cross running water. For example, [Dracula cannot do so](http://www.ibeschool.com/ebook/Dracula.pdf):

> "Thus, whereas he can do as he will within his limit, when he have his
>   earth-home, his coffin-home, his hell-home, the place unhallowed, as
>   we saw when he went to the grave of the suicide at Whitby, still at
>   other time he can only change when the time come. It is said, too,
>   that he can only pass running water at the slack or the flood of the
>   tide."

- Witches, demons and ghosts could not cross water, which [Tam O'Shanter took advantage of.](http://myths.e2bn.org/mythsandlegends/origins870-the-legend-of-tam-o-shanter.html)
- The [Nucklavee fears water](https://books.google.com/books?id=5E4FCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA197&lpg=PA197&dq=nuckelavee%20running%20water&source=bl&ots=APvy735yW9&sig=TgDC5Et2wPO4Tip-5dbsw7qhtmU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQq4rO9f3LAhXGqxoKHTnKDGQQ6AEIPTAI#v=onepage&q=nuckelavee%20running%20water&f=false).

### Especially with regard to witches

And most relevant of all:

- Water was often held to be inimical to witches, such that it could be used as  a test to determine whether an accused individual consorted with the Devil. 
  In [the Book of James, or Daemonologie](http://Book%20of%20James:%20Philomathes%20and%20Epistemon), we have the following quote:

> The other is their fleeting on the water: for as in a secret murther,
>   if the deade carcase be at any time thereafter handled by the
>   murtherer, it wil gush out of bloud, as if the blud wer crying to the
>   heaven for revenge of the murtherer, God having appoynted that secret
>   super-naturall signe, for tryall of that secrete unnaturall crime, so
>   it appeares that God hath appoynted (for a super-naturall signe of the
>   monstruous impietie of the Witches) that the  water shal refuse to
>   receive them in her bosom, that have shaken off them the sacred Water
>   of Baptisme, and wilfullie refused the benefite thereof: No not so
>   much as their eye are able to shed teares (thretten and torture them
>   as ye please) while first they repent (God not permitting them to
>   dissemble their obstinacie in so horrible a crime) albeit the women
>   kinde especially, be able other-waies to shed teares at every light
>   occasion when they will, yea, although it were dissemblingly like the
>   Crocodiles.

Note that the idea **that the very tears of the witches have dried up** seems extraordinarily similar to Baum's assertion that the Wicked Witch "was **so wicked that the blood in her had dried up many years before**."

Comment: This provides some helpful historical context, but doesn't really answer the question as to whether Baum was the first to come up with dousing as a method of _killing_ witches. Yes, water was historically used to test witches, but I don't recall it ever being claimed (other than by Baum) that water was fatal to them.

Comment: @Psychonaut - That’s all there is. There’s the folkloric belief that running water harms evil beings, and the specific application of that to witches. Baum’s *whimsical* version of that seems to be an innovation, but a slight one.